# How To Create Subcategory With A Dot In API Request? (POST request)

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am new to the usage of APIs and I want to use an external one and request some info. However, it states that one value is: your.apikey instead of apikey (meaning without a dot).

apikey is a string, but your is not defined. Do I have to create an empty variable for it?

Here is the code from the documentation. I don't know what the language is, but I need to use:

Variables I need:

```
grdd.example1
grdd.example2
grdd.example3
grdd.example4
```

I need how to get them with grdd. But I have to use grdd, which the type of is not defined as seen in the following code from the documentation

code from documentation:

```
{
    "apikey": "myapikey",
    "grdd": {
        "example1": "e",
        "example2": "e2",
        "example3": 1,
        "example4": 2
    }
}
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

No, The apiKey use like a security token. If you don't have apiKey you cannot access the api endpoints. The api provider give a apiKey then you can access the api endpoints. You have a look https://blog.stoplight.io/api-keys-best-practices-to-authenticate-apis

Comment: Please have a look at my question again. I have edited it.